# jQuery hotkeys triggering too fast: How to catch keypresses slower?

Tags: jquery, keypress, keydown, hotkeys

I'm using jQuery hotkeys plugin with the following code:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'right', function(){
        console.log('fired');
        display_info();
    });
```

When the right button is pressed, the display_info(); is called about 3-4 times. How do I catch the keypresses slower?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try keyup rather than keydown, or build a timer.

Here's a quick and dirty timer I knocked up which should give you a good idea of what you need to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimdotdotdot/bnM4T/6/

Comment: Tried keyup -- still triggering too qcickly. Any advice on how to build a timer? Still new to javascript! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this in case anyone else was experiencing this issue.
The problem you were having sounds exactly like the one I was having.
If I bound multiple shortcut events then each one would execute one less time than the total number of shortcut bindings in the document. I had something like this:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+a', function () {
    alert('A Pressed');
});
$(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+b', function () {
    alert('B Pressed');
});
$(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+c', function () {
    alert('C Pressed');
});
```

For each shortcut bind, I would get the alert two times. The way I solved this was to unbind the shortcut and add a method to handle the alert and unbind.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).bind('keydown.alt+a', 'alt+a', function () {
        alertAndUnbind('A', 'alt+a');
    });
    $(document).bind('keydown.alt+b', 'alt+b', function () {
        alertAndUnbind('B', 'alt+b');
    });
    $(document).bind('keydown.alt+c', 'alt+c', function () {
        alertAndUnbind('C', 'alt+c');
    });
});
function alertAndUnbind(letter, shortcut) {
    alert(letter);
    $(document).unbind('keydown.' + shortcut, shortcut);
});
```

Using unbind in this way allowed me to execute each shortcut's code only once, while retaining the shortcut functionality each time the shortcut is pressed, and keep my code relatively DRY.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'right', function(){
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
            console.log('fired');
            display_info();
    }, 1000);//milliseconds
});
```

Comment: Won't that just make the same number of calls, but one second later?